# Why do Python Tkinter Radio Buttons align left?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having an alignment issue with radio buttons.  I want three columns of form elements.  For some reason, when I add radio buttons to the form, they appear to take up space for a new column on the left.  I was hoping for a simple grid layout with each cell having equal size.  That doesn't appear to be the case.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Radio Button Alignment]

Here is part of my code:

```
    self._mode_state = StringVar()
    self._mode_radio_timelapse = Radiobutton(self, text="Timelapse", command=self._transition(), value=self._timelapse_mode, variable=self._mode_state)
    self._mode_radio_continuous = Radiobutton(self, text="Continuous", command=self._transition(), value=self._continuous_mode, variable=self._mode_state)
    self._mode_radio_ramphold = Radiobutton(self, text="Ramp and Hold", command=self._transition(), value=self._ramp_hold_mode, variable=self._mode_state)
    self._mode_radio_timelapse.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
    self._mode_radio_continuous.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)
    self._mode_radio_ramphold.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=10)

    image_set_label = Label(text="Image Set Type: ")
    image_set_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
    self._image_set_type = Entry()
    self._image_set_type.insert(0, "Ramp")
    self._image_set_type.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `columnspan=2` from `self._image_set_type.grid`?

Comment: Nothing.  It seems to be ignoring that parameter.  The GUI did not change.

Comment: Can you post a sample that I'm able to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widgets are not all on the same grid.  The radio buttons are specifically set with a parent of `self`, but your `Label` and `Entry` widgets are not created with any parent so the parent defaults to the root object.

Here's the fix:

```
image_set_label = Label(self, text="Image Set Type: ") # made self parent
image_set_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
self._image_set_type = Entry(self) # made self parent
self._image_set_type.insert(0, "Ramp")
self._image_set_type.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Bingo!  I was playing with the self attribute when I added the radio button, but forgot about it.  Thank you so much!